# v-icon of vuetify with class 'edit-icon' is not displaying the icon rather it shows the 'edit' text

Tags: material-design, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify 2.2 in my project. In my code, I am using v-icon with class 'edit-icon'. It is supposed to display an edit icon but it is displaying 'edit' as text.
This was working properly but issue started coming once i merged my code to upstream branch. And both the branches have exact same package.config. I even ran my code after `npm install` but still issue is not gone. 
Can someone please guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Sounds like Material Icons aren't loaded/referenced properly

Comment: @Zim can you please tell me how to make sure material icons are loaded properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was indeed with the material icons not being rendered properly as mentioned by @Zim.

[This link](https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.1.34/) has the complete list of material icons that can be used. 
And in this list, there is no `edit` icon. Instead they have `mdi-pencil` for the same purpose. After making that change, I could see the icon being rendered.